# Open source alternative to ARKit

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, slam

I am interested in the Visual Intertial SLAM algorithm that is implemented in the ARKit SDK for motion tracking, that performs visual SLAM and fuses it with intertial data. I understand the algorithm and how tracking is performed.

Since I want to use my custom camera, and not an iphone, I was wondering if there is an equivalent open source implementation available already that performs the VI-SLAM + inertial data for tracking the object, with a comparable performance? I am not looking for SDKs that I can use as APIs, rather algorithm implementations that I can edit myself.
Apologies if this question should belong in another forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a popular [ARToolKit5](https://github.com/artoolkit/ARToolKit5). It is fast, intuitive and cross-platform. You can run it on macOS, iOS, Linux, Android or Windows. It was released in 2015 as a completely open source platform as LGPLv3 and later. There's also a link to the latest release of [ARToolKitX](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx).

Comment: Nice, I will check it out! By any chance, would you happen to know if they fuse IMU data with computer vision for motion tracking, or is it a purely vision based approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source VISLAM on github. I recommend you to try VINS-Mono(https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/VINS-Mono). You can use your own camera to collect images and IMU data, or you can use public datasets.